# Добавить таблицу на страницу Wordpress Через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, table

Есть таблица 3 колонки, и N строк

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

В таблице очень много семантики, которая уже присутствует в статьях. И чтобы поисковики не сканировали и не индексировали данные из таблицы,
Необходимо добавить ее на страницу Wordpress между текстом через js
Подскажите как это можно организовать?
Быть может вывести ее на отдельной странице а потом кодом в статье?
Был бы очень благодарен примерам с кодом и объяснением, АМИНЬ!

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - когда jquery  перестал быть js-ом?

Comment: Спешу разочаровать. Google давно умеет в js. Так что все эти телодвижения ни к чему.

Comment: Тем не менее хотелось бы разобраться в сути вопроса и реализовать это таким образом.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге все оказалось проще
Вставил таблицу в document.getElementById('to_insert').innerHTML = 'TABLE_CODE';
и вывел ее divом